# Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to java.lang.String

Tags: android

I keep getting this Error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to java.lang.String for my
>   dialog box.

I am trying to get the name to show up with the calculation in a dialog box but I get the error above.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   final double tax_Rate = .08;
   final double bonus_Pay_Rate = .1;
   String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
   String hr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your hourly rate");
   double  hourlyRate = Double.parseDouble(hr);
   String hw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your hours worked");
   double hoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(hw);
   double tax = (hoursWorked * hourlyRate) * tax_Rate;
   double pay = hoursWorked * hourlyRate - tax;
   double weeksPay = (pay * bonus_Pay_Rate) + pay;
   String aswner = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (name) + "'s" + "pay this week is: $" + (weeksPay));
```

Comment: Please make your code easier to read, tell us exactly where the error is happening, and get rid of all the code that isn't directly related to the problem.

Comment: I suspect however that your problem is all the lines that look like `String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("...");`. I bet `showInputDialog` returns void, which you're attempting to assign to a String.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign void to a String.

```
String aswner = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,... );
```

`showMessageDialog` returns a `void`, not a `String`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html